# PHP Uploading CAd type files

Tags: php, upload

I am attempting to allow upload of files with extensions .iges, .dxf, .dwg,.
The script will upload jpg, png & pdf file but ones with iges, .dxf, .dwg,.extensions.

This is the code I am using:

// Validate the type. Should be JPEG or PNG.

```
    $allowed = array ('application/pdf', 'application/DXF','application/dxf', 'application/dwg','application/DWG', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/JPG', 'image/X-PNG', 'image/PNG', 'image/png', 'image/x-png',);
    if (in_array($_FILES['upload']['type'], $allowed)) {

        // Move the file over.
        if (move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], "uploads/{$_FILES['upload']['name']}")) {
            echo '<p><em>The file has been uploaded!</em></p>';
        } // End of move... IF.

    } else { // Invalid type.
        echo '<p class="error">Please upload correct file type</p>';
    }
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: Try using file extensions instead of `application/xxx`, see if that helps. Such as `$allowed = array('.iges','.dxf','.dwg','.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.png');` etc.

Comment: And that last comma shouldn't be there, in `'image/x-png',);` it should read as `'image/x-png');` because it probably figures the array still continues.

Comment: Tried that  - didn't work thanks.

Comment: Found this - http://www.dzone.com/snippets/very-simple-php-file-upload, it works!

Comment: Great, so problem solved?

Comment: Well yes thanks, but am keen to sort out the script I posted also